# Navbar stick-top with body 100%

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, height, nav

I am building a react app and have a bootstrap nabavr that is sticky top. I have set the body to be `height: 100%` and when I do this the navbar no longer sticks. I cannot use vh for one of my pages as it messes up the content on mobile so I would like to stick to percentages. Is there a way to do this? I have included the code to make the body 100%.

```
html,
body,
#root {
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Please post all of the relevant code

Answer (score -1):

you can use position CSS property (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position).

If necessary, you can use also z-index property (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index)

Example:

**HTML**

```
<div id="root">
  <nav>
    <div>item</div>
    <div>item</div>
    <!-- ... -->
    <div>item</div>
    <div>item</div>
  </nav>
  <main>
    <!-- ... -->
  </main>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#root {
    /* necessary */
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
}

nav {
    /* necessary */
    position: sticky; // you can also use 'fixed' value
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;

    /* not necessary */
    background-color: red;
    height: 2rem;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

main {
  /* necessary */
  overflow: hidden auto;
  /* margin-top: 2rem; if you have used fixed value */

  /* not necessary */
  height: 200%;
  background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: It would probably be useful for the OP if you could provide an working code sample to illustrate the links you provided.